# Adding multiple table names in Dynamic Dynamo db config file

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, autoscaling

I am using dynamic dynamo db auto scaling.
I can auto scale for my one of my dynamo db table.
But in there ,they did not mention about how to add multiple table names.
If i want to add mytable2, how should i add in below configuration.
Thanks in advance.

[table: ^mytable1$ ]

Comment: what is your configuration..? do you want to add it programatically or by using console ?

Comment: @Chandan i want to add it programatically in config file.

Answer (score 0):

I added  multiple table sections in the config.you can also match multiple tables with one regular expression.